# How to add quantity of same product for same month of same year in SQL query?

Tags: sql

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| product |   date   | quantity |
+---------+----------+----------+
| ITB001  |2022-02-02| 10       |
| ITB001  |2022-03-02| 12       |
| ITBCC1  |2022-02-02| 11       |
| ITB001  |2022-03-02| 7        |
| ITB001  |2022-02-02| 88       |
| MKB114  |2022-03-02| 2        |
| MKB114  |2022-03-02| 97       |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

//need

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| product |   date   | quantity |
+---------+----------+----------+
| ITB001  |2022-02-02| 98       |
| ITB001  |2022-03-02| 19       |
| ITBCC1  |2022-02-02| 11       |
| MKB114  |2022-03-02| 99       |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to understand. Please tell what you want to achieve, what have you tried till now and show your effort about it.

Comment: read about `group by`

Comment: `SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tbl_foo GROUP BY date`

Comment: Try this `select product,date, SUM(quantity) from table_name Group By product , date`

Comment: select product ,date,SUM(quantity) quantity from YourTable GROUP BY   product ,date

Answer (score 0):

Adding quantity of same product for same month of same year.

```sql
select product, SUM(quantity) quantity, datename(year,date) + datename(month,date) as [YearMonth]
from tableName
group by product, datename(year,date) + datename(month,date);
```